# Xcode 5 Build .app without showing package contents

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, build

I have just finished to build my app in Xcode 5 using a cocoa project.

The final result is a .app if I right click on it I can open the folder with all the files in it.

I was wondering if there is a way to build the app without the "Show Package Contents" Option if right clicked.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: On OS X there generally is no "right-click", -- it's control-click. And what purpose exactly would this serve? Cocoa apps are inherently designed to work this way, so unless you change the way OS X operates then maybe you should consider making a command-line application instead.

Comment: Is there any ways to encrypt the resource folder? My app is using a banner with a Quartz Composer view however I don't want to show the composition in resource files.